# How to avoid wrapping text in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a new website I'm building and the CSS forces any text inside h2 tags to wrap whenever there is a space. [Here](http://www.chainedpayments.com/CardSpire/)'s the site:

And here's the problem:

[image]

If I put "Low Fees" together without a space, and even add a few characters ("LowFeesABC"), it stays together and doesn't wrap. I don't know CSS well enough to know how to keep the text together. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't help but see this post as an advertisement.  Sorry if it's legitimate.

Comment: It's not an ad, it's a CSS question. :-|

Comment: @SweatCoder - Please put all of the relevant HTML and JS directly into your question.  That way the code is present after you fix your problem, and this question will be useful to other people.

Comment: It may have been a question, but it was an ad too!  Hence -1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It wraps because the element has a fixed width set on it and the text ”LOW FEES” does not fit into that width. Simply removing `width:90px` removes the wrapping.

Answer (score 48):

```
#topPanel h2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space

Comment: ...just be careful because not all browsers render the same way.  And not all users will have the font.  And (if your website is translated) not all languages have the same length for the equivalent string.  Spacing things exactly can be dangerous.  Specify a width and use either `overflow` or `text-overflow` properties accordingly.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis I'm not really following here. There's not much "exact" in that CSS, aside from saying "don't allow line breaks in text."

Comment: Sorry; to clarify, Matt's answer is *absolutely* correct (+1).  However, based on a number of factors (mentioned above), if your force your text not to wrap, the text could very well go outside of the box that you're hoping it will stay within (which I'm guessing is not the desired behavior).